# Changing color of text in html export from org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

It is possible to specify text modifiers such as bold, italics, strikethrough, etc. in a .org file very easily ([see link](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html)).

Similarly, is there any way to specify text color for just a small section of a .org file such that the text is appropriately colored in the exported html file? I think this would be quite useful while taking highlighted notes fast.

Expected behavior:

```html
This is a sample sentence in normal text color.
<font color="red">
This is a sample sentence in red text color.
</font>
<font color="green">
This is a sample sentence in green text color.
</font>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [macro](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html#Macro-replacement):

```
#+MACRO: color @@html:<font color="$1">$2</font>@@

* This is a test

This is a sample sentence in normal text color.

{{{color(red,This is a sample sentence in red text color.)}}}

{{{color(green,This is a sample sentence in green text color.)}}}
```

with the limitation that the second argument cannot contain a comma (and maybe some other characters).

Comment: Great trick!. It also works with [org-reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal).

Comment: A great list of macros (color, hight light,...) I just found is here: https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros/blob/master/README.org

Answer (score 4):

If you are annoyed by macros. Then add the following to your Emacs config,

```lisp
(org-add-link-type
 "color"
 (lambda (path)
   (message (concat "color "
                    (progn (add-text-properties
                            0 (length path)
                            (list 'face `((t (:foreground ,path))))
                            path) path))))
 (lambda (path desc format)
   (cond
    ((eq format 'html)
     (format "<span style=\"color:%s;\">%s</span>" path desc))
    ((eq format 'latex)
     (format "{\\color{%s}%s}" path desc)))))
```

example in org-mode:

```
    - This is [[color:green][green text]]
    - This is [[color:red][red]]
```

[org-faq](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#org64ae339)